# How to remove tab from child theme added in custom default theme?

Tags: magento

I know, confusing title..

So basically I have an custom theme. The files I'm gonna talk about it located like below :

frontend/custom/default/layout/local.xml

frontend/custom/blue/layout/generallayout.xml

In local.xml, I have added a tab like this

```
<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="tag"><alias>product.tags</alias><title>Product Tags</title><block>tag/product_list</block><template>tag/list.phtml</template></action>
```

Now I wanna remove this tab in blue/generallayout.xml. So I added :

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info.tabs">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>product.tags</name></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

The problem is, this is not working cause I think layout.xml renders after generallayout.xml. So there isnt anything to remove while in generallayout.xml. How I achieve removing the tab ?

I'm sure there isnt anything wrong with what I wrote cause I copied the second snipped to local.xml and I successfully added then removed the tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, I couldn't resolve this with this method. 
I looked at the magento's core php files and saw that 'local.xml' always renders last. No way to change it without overwriting the core files.